# Unable to call Redshift stored procedure using refcursor

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-redshift

I followed this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-result-set.html
But seems to have incomplete, there is no reference to the `statement` object which is used to pull the data from the refcursor

[image]

I tried various things

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.
                    prepareStatement("call myproc( null, null, 3, 4, 'rs' )");
      boolean bb = statement.execute();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("fetch all from rs")
```

The above code is failing with

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: [Amazon][JDBC](11200) Invalid operation for this statement object
```

Also tried to create a new prepareStatement object

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.
                    prepareStatement("call myproc( null, null, 3, 4, 'rs' )");
      boolean bb = statement.execute();
PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement("fetch all from rs")
 ResultSet resultSet = p.executeQuery()
```

The above statement failed with

```
"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","message":"java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: cursor \"rs\" does not exist;"
```

Gradle.properties entry

```
     dependency(group: 'com.amazon.redshift', name: 'redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk', version: '1.2.37.1061')
            dependencySet(group: "com.amazonaws", version: "1.11.688") {
                entry "aws-java-sdk-s3"
                entry "aws-java-sdk-sts"
                entry "aws-java-sdk-redshift"
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few more things and got success.

```
  try (PreparedStatement statement =
                 connection.prepareStatement
                         ("call myproc( null, null, 3, 4, 'rs' )")) {
        statement.execute();
        try (PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement("fetch all from rs")) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = p.executeQuery()) {

            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know why this code work. One thing for refcursor Never set Autocommit to true.